# MongoDB gives "UserNotFound" error when connecting via IP

Tags: mongodb

I have a new mongoDB installation.

I have created an "admin" user per the guidelines here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

I have also made a 'normal' user per step 6 of that guide.

When I use compass to connect to the DB using a hostname of "localhost" and the username "admin" I'm able to connect.  Ditto with the 'normal' user.

I am running the mongod instance bound to the IP XXX.XXX.XXX.16 by way of the following command: mongod --auth --port 27017 --bind_ip xxx.xxx.xxx.16

When I change the hostname in Compass to XXX.XXX.XXX.16, the mongod command window shows the attempted connection and that the connection is accepted... and then says "UserNotFound: Could not find user admin@admin"... and ends the connection.

The full mongod log after hitting 'connect' in Compass looks like this:

```
2018-08-21T14:12:50.321-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2018-08-21T14:13:12.258-0500 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from xxx.xxx.xxx.16:61256 #1 (1 connection now open)
2018-08-21T14:13:12.378-0500 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from xxx.xxx.xxx.16:61256 conn1: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.0.7" }, os: { type: "Windows_NT", name: "win32", architecture: "x64", version: "6.2.9200" }, platform: "Node.js v8.2.1, LE, mongodb-core: 3.0.7", application: { name: "MongoDB Compass Community" } }
2018-08-21T14:13:12.385-0500 I ACCESS   [conn1] SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for admin on admin from client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:61256 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user admin@admin
2018-08-21T14:13:12.488-0500 I COMMAND  [conn1] command admin.system.users appName: "MongoDB Compass Community" command: saslStart { saslStart: 1, mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1", payload: "xxx", autoAuthorize: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 ok:0 errMsg:"Authentication failed." errName:AuthenticationFailed errCode:18 reslen:133 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 102ms
2018-08-21T14:13:12.491-0500 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61256 (0 connections now open)
```

I should note that when I go to 'localhost', nothing registers in the command window.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why... but this fixed the problem:

Built mongod.cfg according to specs here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/

Did NOT use the mongod command-line stuff at all.... and instead just stopped-and-started the windows service.

Now things work.

My thought is that the mongodb service was using the defaults from the cfg file (only binding to 127.0.0.1) and the command switches I gave were being ignored.